# Salvar data atual -X dias numa variável

Tags: cmd, batch

Tenho uma pasta que diariamente são salvos milhares de arquivos de log e quando é preciso procurar um arquivo pela data e hora é um sacrifício.

Tenho como fazer uma rotina para salvar os arquivos atuais numa pasta nomeada com a data, exemplo (20180425), preciso fazer o mesmo para os arquivos antigos, só que para fazer isso eu gostaria de criar uma rotina que ia buscando arquivos com a data atual -365 dias e ia salvando os arquivos com data atual -365 dias que seria uma pasta com o nome (20170425).

Tem alguma forma de salvar a data atual -X dias numa variável para que eu possa alcançar este objetivo?

Preciso fazer isso num batch, pode ser até um executável que dê pra chamar ele colocando o parâmetro da quantidade de dias atrás para que ele retorno qual era a data.

Para salvar a data atual no formato AAAAMMDD eu uso esse comando:

```
SET date=
for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /T') do set date=%%c%%b%%a
```

Para mover os arquivos que quero para essa pasta eu uso esse:

```
forfiles -s -d -0 -m *.log -c "cmd /c move "@path" "%date%" "
```

Comment: Vamos ver se eu entendi, você quer pegar o data de criação do arquivo e separar por pastas? Exemplo: 26-04-2018 18:06 vai criar uma pasta 20180426

Comment: Exatamente isso.

Comment: Deixa eu ver se eu entendi, você quer que por exemplo, um arquivo com a data de criação 13/12/2016 seja jogado para dentro de uma pasta chamada 20161213 ?

Comment: Vc recupera a data do arquivo como ? no nome salvou o pela data de criação do arquivo ?

Comment: @CristianMota, isso mesmo.

Comment: @SachaDee, editei a pergunta colocando os comandos que uso para obter a data atual e mover os arquivos atuais para a pasta.

Comment: certo, aguarde um pouco, irei montar o script para você.. estou no trabalho, antes das 22:00 eu faço.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Supondo que os arquivos estejam no formato **.log** execute o script
>   no mesmo diretório dos arquivos, serão criadas pastas com todas as
>   datas necessárias para fazer a  organização, depois de criadas, será
>   feita uma cópia dos arquivos para a pasta referente à data do arquivo, preservando os arquivos
>   originais.

```
    @echo off

    if not exist %tmp%\SDL (md %tmp%\SDL)

    if exist %tmp%\SDL\logs.txt (del /f /q %tmp%\SDL\logs.txt)
    if exist %tmp%\SDL\datas.txt (del /f /q %tmp%\SDL\datas.txt)
    if exist %tmp%\SDL\x.txt (del /f /q %tmp%\SDL\x.txt)

    dir /b *.log>%tmp%\SDL\logs.txt

    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    for /f %%L in (%tmp%\SDL\logs.txt) do (
    set log=%%L

    for %%E in (!log!) do (
    set data=%%~tE
    set data=!data:~,-6!
    set data=!data: =!

    echo.!data!>%tmp%\SDL\tmp
    for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%G in (%tmp%\SDL\tmp) do (set data=%%I%%H%%G)
    if not exist !data! (MD !data!)
    echo.!data!>>%tmp%\SDL\datas.txt

    echo.!log! !data!>>%tmp%\SDL\x.txt
    )
    )
    )

    for /f "tokens=1-2 delims= " %%K in (%tmp%\SDL\x.txt) do (set f=%%K
    set d=%%L

    copy /a /v "!f!" "!d!"
    )
    pause >nul
```